# Distributed row level locking in Cassandra table OR Achieve higher consistency

Tags: cassandra, datastax

We are using Cassandra DB in our micro service project. In production this service is deployed in PCF that can be scaled up to 6 instances.  We have a table (TableA) with a column (materialSet) as frozen set. In one of the functionality parallel threads are doing below functionality (method is synchronized) –

1. Read TableA to get materialSet
2. Add/remove materials coming from request to/from materialSet
3. Write final materialSet to TableA

With single instance in lower environment of service its working fine. But in production when service scaled up to more than one instance the results in table become inconsistent. The reason is synchronized will work in same JVM but when service gets scaled other instances are running in different JVM and read/writes are happening independently. Is there any way to resolve this? I know probably its bad data model that we are following which is leading us in this problem but we cannot change that.

Any ways to use distributed row level locking in Cassandra table OR any way to achieve higher consistency?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this example from Patrick Callaghan that uses LWTs to enforce cross thread + cross process serializability in an inventory management scenario:

https://github.com/PatrickCallaghan/datastax-transaction-demo

Specifically you may be interested in the query which uses the IF keyword:

```
UPDATE " + tableNameProduct + " SET orderIds=orderIds + {'" + order.getOrderId() + "'},"
            + " capacityleft = " + (lastCapacity-1) + " WHERE productId = '" + order.getProductId() + "' IF capacityleft = " + lastCapacity;
```

https://github.com/PatrickCallaghan/datastax-transaction-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/datastax/transactions/dao/OrderDao.java#L64-L65